# Does Ashiok, Nightmare Muse's ult allow affected adventure cards to be cast as adventures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-adventure-cards

[This is a spoiler for Ashiok, Nightmare Muse](https://i.redd.it/u8uel7rga1441.png), a planeswalker in the upcoming expansion. Their ult reads:

> You may cast up to three face-up cards your opponents own from exile without paying their mana costs.

Certainly, this applies to adventure cards the opponent has exiled by playing them as adventures.

The question is, may the controller of Ashiok cast those adventure cards as adventures, or does the restriction to the non-adventure part from exile apply to all players?

The rules on adventure cards say:

> 715.3d Instead of putting a spell that was cast as an Adventure into its owner’s graveyard as it resolves, its controller exiles it. For as long as that card remains exiled, that player may cast it. It can’t be cast as an Adventure this way, although other effects that allow a player to cast it may allow a player to cast it as an Adventure.

The first half of the third sentence says

> It can’t be cast as an Adventure this way

Does "this way" refer to "anyone casting it from exile", or does it refer to "that player [the player who put it into exile by casting as adventure] casting it from exile"? I am not sure because the second half of the sentence says

> other effects that allow a player to cast it may allow a player to cast it as an Adventure.

which refers to "a player" rather than "that player".

So does that "other effect" specifically have to allow casting the card as an adventure, i.e. Ashiok would only allow the non-adventure part to be cast?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**That ability on Ashiok allows you to cast the Adventure part of the card from exile.**

When a card that is cast as an Adventure resolves and is exiled, it creates a continuous effect that allows you to cast the creature part, and only the creature part, from exile. This is what it means when it says that "it can't be cast as an Adventure this way".

Ashiok ability creates a separate effect that allows you to cast that same card. That effect has no restrictions on what types of spells it can cast, so it can cast either the Adventure part or the creature part of that card from exile.

Comment: Are you sure about that? This is a cost-replacement effect, so wouldn't it disallow you from paying the alternate Adventure cost?

Comment: Would this mean you could cast the same adventure card three times in a turn (ie cast [Stomp](https://scryfall.com/card/eld/115/bonecrusher-giant-stomp))? It looks like Ashiok's ability doesn't care when the card was exiled, and your opponent's still own the adventure cards.

Comment: @nick012000 Casting an Adventure spell is not an alternate cost, it is an alternate way of casting a card, like casting one side of a split card vs the other, or casting a card with Morph face down.

Comment: @Malco Ashiok's ability allows you to cast spells during the resolution of the ability. Once you choose to cast a card that way, you put it on the stack, and then it's not in exile anymore. By the time the spell resolves, Ashiok's ability has long since resolved, so nothing lets you cast spells like that from exile.

Comment: Ahh my bad, I missed that the ability doesn't have the "until end of turn." text à la Chandra, Fire Artisan and the other red "cas/play from exile" cards they have been doing lately.

Comment: Those red cards are usually doing some variation of "impulse draw", where you exile cards from the library, and then have the turn to play them, like drawing into a temporary hand. Ashiok is taking cards that have been exiled by other effects, probably on other turns, and now allowing you to cast them.

Answer (score 1):

When a card says "you may do X", and then says "if you do X this way", that means "if you use 'you may do X' to do X". In a related [question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/47021/do-bolass-citadel-and-experimental-frenzy-take-reduced-mana-cost-into-account), someone asked about Bolas's Citadel and Experimental Frenzy. Both allow you to cast the top card of your library, but Bolas's Citadel has you pay life rather than mana:

> You may play the top card of your library. If you cast a spell this way, pay life equal to its converted mana cost rather than pay its mana cost.

If you have both cards out, you can choose which one you use to allow you to cast the top card of your library. Bolas's Citadel's "If you cast a spell this way, pay life equal to its converted mana cost rather than pay its mana cost" means that if Bolas's Citadel's ability is the ability you choose to allow you to cast the spell, you pay life. If you choose to have  Experimental Frenzy's ability be what allows you to cast it, then you pay mana.

With your question, if you use an Adventure card's own "For as long as that card remains exiled, that player may cast it." ability to cast it, then it can't be cast as an adventure.

> So does that "other effect" specifically have to allow casting the card as an adventure

Ashiok allows you to cast the card. Normally, when you cast an Adventure card you choose whether to cast it as an Adventure or Creature. There is nothing in the wording of Ashiok's ability that changes that. So if it is Ashiok that you are relying on to cast the card, you can cast it as an Adventure.

If you were somehow in a situation where you could use Ashiok's ability or the Adventure card's own ability to cast it (which normally wouldn't arise, since Ashiok says "opponent", but most things in MtG have some exception), then whether you could cast it as an Adventure would depend on which you chose to use.

Comment: It's impossible to have both permissions usable at the same time because Ashiok's ability only allows you to cast spells during the resolution of the ability, and you can't normally cast spells for any other reason during that time.

Comment: @murgatroid99 not impossible - Adventures are castable by the *controller* of the adventure spell, while Ashiok cares about the *owner* of the exiled spells.

Comment: That's not what I was talking about. The Adventure effect allows you to cast the spell when you would normally be able to do so, i.e. when you have priority and (in general) when the stack is empty. Ashiok's ability allows you to cast the spell during the resolution of the ability, at which time you don't have priority. So, those are mutually exclusive.